# Can I give zakath to husband?

Tags: zakat, wife, husband, loan, debt

My husband has a loan and I am also involved in it. He do repay the loan as installments. I own jewelry and have no further earnings right now. If my husband help me with money to give my zakath can I give that back to my husband as zakath?

Comment: Allah says:"Zakah expenditures are only for the poor and for the needy and for those employed to collect [zakah] and for bringing hearts together [for Islam] and for freeing captives [or slaves] and for those in debt and for the cause of Allah and for the [stranded] traveler - an obligation [imposed] by Allah . And Allah is Knowing and Wise."(9:60) be aware that scholars consider the order as crucial.